# ERROR "member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type"

Tags: c#

I need to open a FrmEscalacao that sends information of FrmAdmin  to FrmEscalacao with a string called "time"

here is the code of FrmAdmin

```
public partial class FrmAdmin : Form
{
    private string time;

    public FrmAdmin(string time)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.time = time;
    }

    public void btnEscalar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        FrmEscalacao f1 = new FrmEscalacao();
        f1.ShowDialog();
    }
```

}

here is the code of FrmEscalacao

```
public partial class FrmEscalacao : Form
{
    public string time;

        private void FrmEscalacao (string time)
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            this.time = time;

            SQLiteConnection ocon = new SQLiteConnection(Conexao.stringConexao);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ocon.Open();
            SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = new SQLiteCommand("Here is the SQL command");
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(table);
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = table;
            DataTimes.DataSource = bs;
            ocon.Close();

        }
```

And it returns an error at

```
private void FrmEscalacao (string time)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have only constructor matching the name of the class.
If it's the declaration of the constructor, then it should be

```
public FrmEscalacao(string time) {...}
```

Constructors should not have any return type. And you shouldn't declare it `private`, if it's going to be used to create an instanse of that type; it should be `public`.

Then you should use it:

```
FrmEscalacao f1 = new FrmEscalacao("your time");
```

that is, you must specify the value for `time` argument of type `string`.

Comment: If i use "public" instead of private void, it creates another error and does not solve the “member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type” this is the error it creates: " FrmEscalacao.cs does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments"

Comment: @user1748580 remove `void` from constructor declaration and still make it public

Comment: @user1748580 Besides use `FrmEscalacao f1 = new FrmEscalacao("your time");` to initialize it. You've declared a constructor with an argument, so use should supply the argument, or another constructor without it...

Comment: Yes, it fixed the second error "contructor that takes 0 arguments" but the first error remains.

Comment: @user1748580 did you remove `void` from constructor declaration?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an argument to the constructor.

So, either add another method as follows:

```
public FrmEscalacao()
{
    //all your code
}
```

Also, change your constructor to public void on the constructor that takes an argument.

```
public FrmEscalacao(string time)
{
    //all your code
}
```

Constructors automatically don't return anything, so you don't need to mark them void.